# What is 20/20 hindsight?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Water – or at least ice – occurred on all the moons of Jupiter. And there were continuously erupting volcanoes on Io – so it was reasonable to expect weaker activity on the world next door. Putting these two facts together made European life seem not only possible, but inevitable – as most of nature's surprises are, *when viewed with 20/20 hindsight*. - *2010: Odyssey Two*, Arthur C. Clarke

I just don't understand what this 20/20 hindsight is. Is it a parlance?

Comment: "20/20 hindsight" is a fairly common expression that should be easily searchable.  Please include your own research with your question.

Answer (score 3):

It's a semi-humorous expression.

20/20 is a measure of normal vision (or perfect vision); that is, someone who can see the same things that most people can see at a range of 20 feet has "[20/20 vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_acuity)". In a more common measurement system this would be 6/6 vision (6 metres being roughly 20 feet). The fact that "20/20" is used almost as a shorthand way of saying perfect vision (whether literal vision or metaphorical vision) is probably more down to the influence of Hollywood than to the influence of optometrists.

It is of course easier to see that things were going to inevitably occur after they happened than it is to predict them before they happen. That is, to see them in hindsight than it is to see them with foresight.

So "20/20 hindsight" just means that "anyone with a normal range of perception should have been able to see this result coming".

Of course, in real life they usually don't (because if they did, we'd all be rich from picking stocks on the stock market), which is where the humour comes from.

Comment: @ medica : Ha! Funny you should say that! At the very time that you posted that comment I was editing the answer to fix that very issue. You are of course correct.

Comment: "anyone with a normal range of perception should have been able to see this result coming" isn't how I understand this idea. Rather, it's "now that we see the past, we should have realized what would happen."  With your version, me saying "Oh well, hindsight is 20/20" regarding an action I took would be me accepting responsibility for a mistake.  With my version, it's merely saying "any mistake I made was due only to a lack of information."

Comment: @Alan K--It's clear you're British, or at least not American.  Here in the US, 6/6 vision is unheard of, and 20/20 vision is normal--linguistically as well as medically.

Comment: @Nathaniel : I don't agree that "anyone with a normal range of perception should have been able to see this result coming" has any element of mistake or blame attached. It is simply a statement that given the information available a theoretical person SHOULD have been able to see the outcome... yet time and again science history shows that this is much easier to do in hindsight than in foresight. Also yours does not seem to tie to the A. C. Clarke quote in the original question. The quotation indicates that the information WAS there, it's just that the right conclusion wasn't drawn from it.

Comment: @Steven Littman. "Not American" is most of the world, Steve. You guys kicked the Brits out 239 years ago and their awful currency along with them (something which took us until 1966, and they didn't do themselves until 1971); why oh why couldn't you have done the same with feet, pounds and furlongs! (Come to the decimal side, it's nice over here...)

Comment: We have 2-liter bottles of soda here (note the spelling) and we have the 100-meter dash (likewise), but we're tenacious.  Football (our version) would likely be very weird on a 100-meter field.

Comment: @Steven Littman :Ha! It's a start, my friend, it's a start! Give it time and you'll come to love those little 10's. (Though I admit that Celsius will take some adapting to; an American friend of mine made the quite valid point that the finer graduations in deg F make it easier to get a "feel" for the forecast.)

Comment: 20/20 hindsight does not mean "anyone with a normal range of perception should have been able to see this result coming".  It means that with clear vision of everything that has transpired up to now, it's easy to look back and see what the correct course of action should have been.  Since no one can see into the future to see how today's choices will play out, we are making decisions, more or less blindly, without the benefit of 20/20 hindsight.

Answer (score 0):

As Alan K states, 20/20 vision is considered "perfect" vision, so the term 20/20 hindsight means that, when looking over a situation after it has occurred and you already know the outcome or have the answer to the question, the outcome or answer seems obvious. You feel like it is something you should have known or seen in the moment.

For example:

"I think of all of those times that Bill said his boss gave him a last minute assignment that just had to be completed before he came home... I should have known he was lying. We were newlyweds. I believed he was just working hard to build our future together. But then one night I saw him with her... hindsight is 20/20."

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'm having a bit of difficulty sorting out the difference between your answer and that of Alan K., posted 20 minutes ago. Would it be possible to emphasize the aspect of it that is different? (This may totally be because I'm a native speaker, so it seems self-evident to me...) Thanks, and again, welcome.

Comment: I didn't feel that answer conveyed effectively that the term is used to describe a situation in the past that, with the information available to the person in the future, should have been obvious to them. It has to do with second guessing your ideas from the past and is used to convey reflection based on new information.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a slight misuse of the term.  The adage in English is "Hindsight is 20/20," that is, once an event has occurred, it's easy to see why and how it happened.  Before the event occurred, the whys and hows of the eventual outcome might well have been difficult to discern even for the perceptive.  The animated show *South Park* has a character called Captain Hindsight who provides obvious solutions that should have been implemented before it was too late.  (For the amusement, click [here](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=captain%20hindsight%20south%20park%20compilation).) But the term applies equally to those solutions that were not obvious before events came to pass.

(In the expression, 20/20, the numerator applies to the person's vision, and the denominator applies to normal vision.  The test is usually reading letters.  If you have 20/20 vision, that means that that you can read at 20 units (say, feet), no further and no nearer, what people of normal vision can read as 20 units.  If you're farsighted, you'll measure something like 40/20:  what normally-sighted people need to get to within 20 feet to read, you'll be able to read at 40 feet.  If you're nearsighted, you'll measure something like 20/400:  What normally-sighted people can read at 400 feet, you'll have to approach to within 20 feet to read.)

Comment: Um... Sure, Arthur C. Clarke was no James Joyce, but he was a really, really smart guy, and (not to make a fallacious logical jump) I honestly don't think it's a misuse of the term here. Seriously, even if Dan Brown wrote this (which is a laughable idea in and of itself), I wouldn't label it a misuse. (Oh, wait, didn't we spar over Dan Brown before? If so, sorry. Change that to Edward Bulwer-Lytton.)

Comment: far-sightedness is often spec'd by changing the denominator:  20/17, 20/15 etc. I can see at 20 what normal people can only see at 15.

Comment: @medica I sure your comment is exceedingly droll.  And I'm sure that the fact that it's lost on me means that I'm not a really, really smart guy.  Clarke wasn't as good a writer as Joyce, and maybe not as smart, but surely a better writer than *and* smarter than Brown?  What does this have to do with hindsight, which is always 20/20 since we don't have to guess the outcome of events?  This makes "20/20 hindsight" a bit redundant, which reflects neither on Clarke's intelligence or his writing.  But if you "honestly" disagree, who am I to question?

Comment: I agree with your explanation but I also see no "misuse" here. Yes, the phrase being referenced is "hindsight is 20/20", but "with 20/20 hindsight" makes reference to it without "misusing" anything. It's saying "with hindsight, which is 20/20", with fewer words and less awkwardly. No part of it could be left out, or rearranged, without changing the intended meaning.

Comment: @hobbs "20/20 hindsight" refers to the hindsight that is 20/20, which admits of other kinds of hindsight, say, 40/20 hindsight or 20/400 hindsight.  Since all hindsight is 20/20 -- the meaning of the adage -- the fraction could be omitted without  changing the meaning.  If you feel that it works as a literary trope, who am I  to say otherwise?  Thus my use of the word "slight."

Comment: Do you object to "dim candlelight" as well? :)